# Edit datetime for manipulation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, group-by

I have a list of customer orders for certain products, quantity and weight.
I would like to forecast the orders by month, but my dates are displayed as DD-MM-YY date format
I want to groupby the orders by month
And in general it will display the indexes as MM-YY
But when I try to see the graph of the activity it shows an error - that it does not represent DATETIME

I looked in several places, the date was according to all the first of the month

like:

[image]

my df

| report | record | order | costum | weight | pacs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-01-01 | 9251498 | 56102231 | 1722269783 | 40008 | 2180 |
| 2018-01-02 | 7793624 | 39415480 | 1381891750 | 30442 | 1542 |
| 2018-01-03 | 3226387 | 17498214 | 693174883 | 7392 | 433 |
| 2018-01-04 | 10776575 | 42169362 | 952243860 | 25004 | 1143 |
| 2018-01-05 | 19202137 | 69641658 | 2768404148 | 32757 | 1735 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2022-12-05 | 7104577 | 73850036 | 4601227782 | 80632 | 3644 |
| 2022-12-06 | 15784623 | 172962196 | 3687453925 | 90093 | 5951 |
| 2022-12-07 | 12535246 | 140712899 | 2404893824 | 40925 | 2077 |
| 2022-12-09 | 18803968 | 958553920 | 4272267486 | 63685 | 3272 |
| 2022-12-10 | 13625781 | 712363975 | 1501627450 | 102527 | 5312 |

2:
I want to do the prediction also by product type
Is there a way to create like a pivot table
or through convenient presentation
I would appreciate tips and help

Comment: Try referring to the datetime module documentations for converting DD-MM-YY to YY-MM-01. Here's the link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the index to datetime format, then you can cast it to a [PeriodIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y-%m-%d')
df.index = df.index.to_period("M")
```